# ReferenceError when trying to new up 'Audio' object within web worker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

```
function buildBlobUrl(func) {
  let blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(['(',
    func.toString(),
    ')()'
  ], {
    type: 'application/javascript'
  }));
  return blobUrl;
}

function webWorkerFunction() {
  let audio = new Audio();
}

let blobUrl = buildBlobUrl(webWorkerFunction);
let webWorker = new Worker(blobUrl);
```

If I run the above code, I get an error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: Audio is not defined`. Is there anyway I can utilize the [Audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio) object within my web worker function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No,

The `Audio` constructor does return an `HTMLAudioElement` DOM Element, and Web Workers don't have access to the DOM, we thus can't create DOM Elements from there.
And since we still can't really have a BaseAudioContext in a Worker either, there is no true alternative to playing this media 100% from the Worker.